# Rails 4.0.2 and sqlite PRAGMA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I'd like to set in Rails 4.0.2, using sqlite3,

```
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = true
```

I guess I can specify some kind of option on `config/database.yml` or `config/environment.rb` but surfing the web did not provide me any solution.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using **options** on database.yml:

```
adapter: sqlite
database: "yourfile"
options: "PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = true"
```